# how can i edit swf file in flash cs4?

Tags: html, apache-flex, flash

i have a player which is of swf file. I need to edit it to remove user defined conextmenu.( when i right click its showing one name, i need to remove that)

Can any one help me how to do that.

how i can edit swf file in flash. when i open swf file in flash am unable to edit anything.

u can see the flash player here 
http://test2.musicking.in/video/4/abd 
Please need help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Flash CS4 would require the source FLA/AS files for the player, it doesn't edit SWF files. There is the option of reverse engineering the SWF if the license you have allows it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've got the source, you can't edit it in the Flash IDE.  You can usually import some assets, but that's about it.  Your best bet is probably something like this:

http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/

Comment: Right.  Flash doesn't allow editing the .swf.  You would need the .fla.

Comment: using swfd ecompiler we can convert swf to fla rite

Comment: Yes, but the result won't always re-compile, and may require tweaking/re-building.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it first to `.fla` and then edit it.

Here is a [link to the free download of swf to fla converter](http://www.sothink.com/product/flash...r/download.htm).